# Remove() at LinkedList

Tags: java

`Link` class:

```
class Link {
    public String data1;
    public Link nextLink;

    //Link constructor
    public Link() {
        data1 = null;
    }

    public Link(String data) {
        data1 = data;
    }

    public Link getNext() {
        return nextLink;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data1;
    }

    //Print Link data
    public String printLink() {
        return "{" + data1 + "}";
    }
}
```

`SimpleLinkedList` class:

```
class SimpleLinkedList {
    private Link first;

    //LinkList constructor
    public SimpleLinkedList() {
        first = null;
    }

    //Returns true if list is empty
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    //Inserts a new Link at the first of the list
    public void add(String d1) {
        Link link = new Link(d1);
        link.nextLink = first;
        first = link;
    }

    //Deletes the link at the first of the list
    public String remove() {
        Link temp = first;
        first = first.nextLink;
        return temp.toString();
    }

    public String get(int index) {
    // post: returns the element at the specified position in this list.
        // index must be 1 or higher
        if (index <= 0)
            return null;

        Link current = first.getNext();
        for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
            if (current.getNext() == null)
                return null;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return current.getData();
    }

    //Prints list data
    public String toString() {
        Link currentLink = first;
        String output = "";
        System.out.print("List: ");
        while (currentLink != null) {
            output += currentLink.printLink();
            currentLink = currentLink.nextLink;
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

This is the linked list that i implemented. But in remove method I want it to remove from head and return the string that is removed. Couldnt manage to do that.

Comment: Edit your post, some code is outside of the code tags.

Comment: *"Couldnt manage to do that."* Is that all of explanation we can get? No exception, no compiler error, no info on what went wrong?

Comment: I'd say OP was just lazy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the data of the removed `Link` :

```
public String remove() {
    Link temp = first;
    first = first.nextLink;
    return temp.getData();
}
```